# How to find a summation of a logarithmic function?

Tags: functions, logarithms, exponential-sum

Suppose that I had to find $\log_{10}(8952!)$. Now, since $\log(a) + \log(b) = \log(ab)$, this can be rewritten to the following summation:

$$\sum_{x=1}^{8952}{\log_{10}(x)}$$

Would there be a general way to compute this in terms of $\log_{10}(x)$?

Comment: Did you try wolfram Alpha's computational engine?

Answer (score 7):

[Stirling's approximation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) gives a pretty tight bound for the *natural* logarithm of $n!$ (but not an exact value), and then the base-10 logarithm is only a matter of dividing by $\ln 10$.

Comment: Nice answer. It is also possible to get even better approximations using Euler-Maclaurin formula i think. Not ?

Comment: There are lots of versions of Stirling's formula. Euler-Maclaurin for $\ln(n!)$ corresponds to one of them.